# Change URL based on cell value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am complete beginner so apologise in advance if question is too basic. How do I make url to change automatically basaed on what is in cell B3? I'm using json within Google Apps Script.

For example, if my url is  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask , how would I replace 'ask' with whatever is in cell B3?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? (And can you include a simple setup of your sheet?

Answer (score 1):

The best way for this is to use a formula

```
=HYPERLINK("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/" & B3, B3)
```

[image]